# The distribution of X while the distribuition of X|Y and Y are given.

Tags: probability

Is there a way of getting the distribuition of X when the distribution of X|Y and Y is given? Been circling around this problem for a long time, could use some help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These distributions are connected through the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.  I visualize the distributions as the continuous limit of a discrete histogram over a two-dimensional field.  The $f_Y$ distribution gives, for each grid row $(\cdot, y)$, how much of the distribution is in that row, while the $f_{X \mid Y}$ distribution gives, for each grid square $(x, y)$, how much of the distribution is in that square—normalized for the row to sum to $1$.

Thus, to obtain the joint distribution $f_{X, Y}$, which is normalized to sum to $1$ across the entire field, you should be able to just multiply them:

$$
f_{X, Y}(x, y) = f_{X \mid Y} (x \mid y) \, f_Y(y)
$$

That is, the amount of distribution in a grid square is equal to the amount of distribution in a row, times the fraction of that row that goes into that grid square.  Then, $f_X(x)$ gives how much of the distribution is in the grid column $(x, \cdot)$, so we should just sum up (i.e., integrate) over that column:

$$
f_X(x) = \int f_{X, Y}(x, y) \, dy
$$

Comment: thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X|Y}(x,y) \cdot f_Y(y)
$$
so
$$
f_X(x)
 = \int_\mathbb{R}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy
 = \int_\mathbb{R} f_{X|Y}(x,y) \cdot f_Y(y) dy
$$